# QGIS: Search for unknown number of clusters (of parcels)

Tags: qgis, clustering

I have data on various geographic parameters (e.g. roads, forest...) + on parcels (again vectors and parcel numbers as attribute to it). Based on the defined criteria (this I've done already through Clip and Difference etc.) I'd like to get a list of parcels. This can be done reasonably easily.

The problem I have is: Within the defined area (clipped) I want to group neighboring parcels into clusters (e.g. min. 10ha). In another words, I don't want to get only parcels larger than 10ha, but clusters of neighboring parcels (which can be smaller) that fulfill the criteria -- I don't know how many clusters.

The output I imagine as a table with ID# of the cluster (can be simple 1,2,3...) and parcel numbers (attribute of the layer).